# How to specify sandbox directory for runhaskell?

Tags: haskell, ghci, runhaskell

By default, runhaskell seems to ignore shared sandbox paths.

When running a haskell file from the command line using runhaskell, how do I set the sandbox directory?

Comment: The question is good on its own. But you may be asking the wrong question; are you aware of `cabal repl`, `cabal run`, and `cabal exec`, which start `ghci`, an executable from your `*.cabal` file, and an arbitrary process, respectively, with environment variables set that inform GHC of the appropriate paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sandboxes are a concept specific to Cabal, and runhaskell (and the rest of the GHC suite) has no idea about them. The relevant concept to GHC is the package database path, which can be controlled either by command-line flags like `-package-db` or by the environment variable `GHC_PACKAGE_PATH`. `runhaskell` seems not to support `-package-db`, so setting `GHC_PACKAGE_PATH` is the best bet. Or of course you can let Cabal do the work with `cabal exec` as Daniel Wagner pointed out in a comment.

`cabal exec` works by setting `GHC_PACKAGE_PATH`, so if for some reason you want to set the variable manually, you can see what value Cabal sets it to with the command `cabal exec printenv GHC_PACKAGE_PATH`.